# WPF Socket client structuring

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, mvvm

my question might seem a bit odd, but what would be the best approach to create a WPF Socket client using the MVVM pattern.

Right now on my ViewModel, i create a thread, which attempts to connect to the server in a while loop, and wait for connection, after it's connected it gets data from the server.

Is there a better way to make it so i won't have to use a new Thread while not blocking the main UI thread?

Relevant ViewModel code:

```
    serverInfo.ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
serverInfo.PORT = 1488;
//Initialize LeecherList
p_LeecherList = new ObservableCollection<LeecherDetails>();
//Subscribe to CollectionChanged Event
p_LeecherList.CollectionChanged += OnLeecherListchanged;

AccountsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Accounts.json")));
foreach (var x in AccountsInfo.Accounts)
{
    p_LeecherList.Add(new LeecherDetails("N/A", x.Email, x.Password, false, "Collapsed"));
}

base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("LeecherList");

Thread ConnectionLoop = new Thread(() =>
{
    ServerStatus = "Connecting...";
    while (true)
    {
        if (!serverInfo.HasConnectedOnce && !serverInfo.ClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                serverInfo.ClientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, serverInfo.PORT);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
            }
        }
        else if (serverInfo.ClientSocket.Connected && !serverInfo.HasConnectedOnce)
        {
            serverInfo.HasConnectedOnce = true;
            ServerStatus = "Online";
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var buffer = new byte[8000];
            int received = serverInfo.ClientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
            if (received == 0) return;
            var data = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, data, received);
            var st = helper.ByteToObject(data);
            if (st is string info)
            {
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
});
ConnectionLoop.IsBackground = true;
ConnectionLoop.Start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now on my ViewModel, i create a thread, which attempts to connect to the server in a while loop, and wait for connection, after it's connected it gets data from the server.
>
> Is there a better way to make it so I won't have to use a new Thread while not blocking the main UI thread?

Well; you should put this logic in a kind of `Service`.

Example:

---

So, you could create a service like this, note: the start,  stop and the event to pass the data.

The basic idea is to move the more business like communication logic in a separate service, so that, if you need to change it later on, the logic is more isolated and not mixed with your viewmodel.

```
//note, you could encapsulate functionality in an interface, e.g.: IService
public class SomeService 
{
     public event EventHandler<YourEventData> OnSomethingHappening;
     public SomeService(some parameters)
     {
         //some init procedure
     }

     public void Stop()
     {
        //your stop logic
     }

     public void Start()
     {
        //your start logic
     }

     private void Runner() //this might run on a seperate thread
     {
         while(running)
         { 
             if (somecondition)
             {
                  OnSomethingHappening?.Invoke(this, new YourEventData());
             }
         }
     }

     public string SomeFooPropertyToGetOrSetData {get;set;}
}
```

Create one of these somewhere in your application, perhaps at startup.

Then pass it to your viewmodel, maybe through the constructor. In that case your viewmodel will look something like this:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     private SomeService_service;
     public YourViewModel(SomeServiceyourService)
     {
          _service = yourService;
          _service.OnSomethingHappening += (s,a) =>
          {
              //event handling
          };
     }
}

//etc.
```

Comment: Would it be smart to pass the ViewModel to the service ? like how commands work.

Comment: No, normally you would pass the service to the viewmodel.... and update values in the viewmodel through events... the "viewmodel" is "consuming" the "service", not the other way round.

Comment: Besides, when doing this correctly, your service should be independent of the viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you, i will play around it and see what i can come up with.

Comment: Your welcome, good luck and let me know. Btw, thanks is preferably expressed as upvote and/or marking as answer ;-)